# Gridview OnRowDataBound loop through cells

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.net 4. How do I loop and read the value of each cell in a row with the OnRowDataBound event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView id="testGrid" OnRowDataBound="testGrid_RowDataBound" ... runat="server">
    ......
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void testGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string val = string.Empty;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach(TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            val = cell.Text;
    }
}
```